# A-2-Z web hosting on Amazon AWS

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, amazon-web-services

All,

I am studying web dvp, and one of my classes is project-based.  We have to build a functional site that demonstrate our understanding of:

- HTML,
- CSS,
- Javascript,
- php,
- MySQL,
- And potentially Ajax or some other web component.

For the project, we can use a local server using WampServer and basically build the site entirely on our laptop.  If I have time, I would like to create a real site, and I thought it would be a good way to familiarize myself with Amazon's AWS services.  So if I purchase a domain name, can I rely on AWS to host the site from A-to-Z?  I understand I can use AWS to host content, the database, and do the background computations, if needed.  What else do I need and what are the parts that AWS cannot help me with?

Second, is there good documentation for a beginner to navigate AWS and learn how to use it (either on Amazon, or some 3rd party sites, or even a good book, as long as is up to date).  The ideal documentation would be a tutorial on creating a web site from a-to-z on AWS, as detailed as possible.

As you can guess, I have limited understanding of the IT issues.  I have 0 Linux or sysadmin experience, but this is a good opportunity to change that.  I hope you can help me.

Thank you,

JDelage

PS:  Please keep the answers AWS-specific.  At this point, I am only interested in alternative services to the extent that they plug a hole in Amazon's offering.

Comment: the first flaw in your plan for a "real" site is relying on amazon - ec2 isn't reliable for a "real" site but should be fine for a class project

Comment: I totally disagree with Jim B's comment.  EC2 is being used for some some very large production web sites; see http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat an EC2 instance just like a physical server; you get full root access to the instance and can install and configure it however you like.  Apart from registering your domain name with a DNS provider, you'll be able to do all the rest of your site set-up using AWS.

The [EC2 getting started guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/) is a nice introduction and should get you up and running.  Post a comment here if you have more questions, and good luck !

Comment: Thanks Gareth.  I'll have more questions later on for sure.